# How to find an antiderivative of f double prime x?

Tags: calculus

For this question, wouldn't the answer just be $f'(4)-f'(1)$? I'm not exactly sure if I'm right or how to further solve this question. Can someone please help me out?

Suppose that $f(1)=2 ,f'(1) =5, f'(4) = 3$ and f'' is continuous. Find the value of $$\int_{1}^{4}f''(x)dx$$

Comment: Please tell us what you think.

Comment: Such a problem statement is unlikely. Double check it.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say $f'(4) = 3$?

Comment: Check my edit. Yes, it's f'(4)

Comment: f'(4)=3. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

For the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

$$\int_{1}^{4}f''(x)dx=f'(4)-f'(1)=3-5=-2$$

Comment: Check my edit. f'(4) = 3

Answer (score 0):

The definite integral is $f'(4)-f'(1)$. As $f'(4)$ is unknown and unconstrained, the integral can be anything.

Comment: Looks like OP has edited their question, $f'(4) = 3$.

Comment: @AndrewLi: that was strongly expected...